# Spring Batch - dynamic job selection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm getting familiar with Spring Batch because i believe that is what our project needs to replace our current codebase (to make developments quicker and easier to test).

Our current codebase has the following, important, characteristics:

- One codebase - but a lot of batch processes (we reuse code between batch processes)
- Currently, we have multiple main() methods in the codebase and just have different shell scripts to invoke the proper main Class.

I'm looking to tackle the following problem in Spring batch:

I've started a dummy, experimenting project based on the Spring Batch Example: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

I would like to keep multiple batch processes (Jobs, i take, if we talk Spring Batch) in the same codebase. However, currently, if i add more Job sin my code, all of them get executed. Even worse, I've added an Application Listener in my SpringBoot main class and it turned out, the Jobs get executed before the ApplicationReadyEvent - this seems quite bad to me, almost like running business logic in a constructor.

My question is:

- How can i select which job i want to run (based on command line arguments)
- How can i make sure that the job is started AFTER the ApplicationReadyEvent

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was the following:

- Set the spring.batch.job.enabled property to false - this prevented jobs to start when the context was setup
- Get the JobLauncher out of the context and run any Job myself:

  ```
  SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(BatchProcessingServiceStarter.class);
  app.setWebEnvironment(false); 

  ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx=app.run(args);
  JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
  JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
      .addDate("date", new Date())
      .toJobParameters();  

  if(!"1".equals(args[0])){       
      jobLauncher.run(ctx.getBean("BatchConfiguration2", Job.class), jobParameters);                   
  } else {
      jobLauncher.run(ctx.getBean("BatchConfiguration1",  Job.class), jobParameters);   
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

There are various questions.

1.
To disable starting all jobs automatically on startup just configure this [Spring Boot property](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties):

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false # Do not execute all Spring Batch jobs in the context on startup.
```

2.
You would run job like this:

```
java -Dspring.batch.job.names=prepareTeaJob -jar target/0910-job-parameters-cli-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar sugarAmount="no sugar"
```

sugar amount there is Job parameter. Full example belonging to this listing is hosted in [my Github Repository here](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/09-batch/0910-job-parameters-cli). BTW, there are much more examples covering these various Spring Batch topics if you are learning Spring Batch.

3.
Not sure what you are referring to as "ApplicationReadyEvent". AFAIK job should be executed after the Spring context it fully initialized.